# Syntax error at the end of input when executing psycopg2

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I am trying to add a COLUMN to certain table using psycopg2, from a Django function to a table in PostgreSQL. The name of the column is define in the views.py file of the Django project.

I have been trying with a some similar questions in stack over flow but none have worked for me.

View:

```
def parameter_creation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    min_value = request.POST['min_value']
    max_value = request.POST['max_valu']

if ParameterModel.objects.filter(name=unidecode(name.upper())).exists():
    return JsonResponse('name', safe = False)
else:
    form = New_Parameter_Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        info = form.save(commit = False)
        info.name = unidecode(name.upper())
        data_analysis.column_aggregation(name)
```

data_analysis function:

```
def column_aggregation(name_column):
    cursor.execute("""ALTER TABLE simulated_data ADD COLUMN %s""" % 
    name_column)
    cursor.commit()
```

Once the code is executed, the output is the next error:

```
cursor.execute("""ALTER TABLE simulated_data ADD COLUMN %s""" % 
name_column)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE simulated_data ADD COLUMN Eng_temp
```

Comment: Why are you not using Django migrations?

Comment: You are getting that error because you have not included the data type of the column

Comment: That makes sense a lot, thanks Ianin, do you know what is the way to define the data type  of the column, using this method

Comment: If you wish to use this method you need include a data type from the table that can be found here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE

Comment: I don't know your exact use case but I would suggest never letting users create columns in your database

Comment: I am trying to do give that access just to some profiles

Comment: Even so - it is very difficult to test an application where you have no idea of the schema that you are reading. I would suggest creating a key/value model that can contain dynamic attributes for your model and maybe an "Attribute" model that contains the keys

Comment: Thanks Iain, all your suggestions are highly welcome